# Angular2 add class to parent component on child event execution

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-template

I am working on a project using Angular2 and until now find it awesome!
But on the other hand, I find some pretty simple tasks frustrating.

Well, what I am trying to do is pretty simple:

In my app I have a **header** component (reusable through all app) and a **search-bar** component.

The Header component looks like that:

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {IONIC_DIRECTIVES} from 'ionic-angular';
import {SearchBar} from './../../component/search/search.component';

@Component({
    selector        : 'med-header',
    templateUrl     : 'build/component/header/header.component.html',
    directives      :   [IONIC_DIRECTIVES, SearchBar]
})

export class Header {
    @Input()
    showLogo : number;
    /**
     * constructor
     */
    constructor(){
    }
};
```

And the template:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      <img *ngIf="showLogo" src="build/assets/images/logo.png" id="main-logo" />
    </ion-title>
    <div id="search-box"><med-search></med-search></div>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

And the search bar component:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {IONIC_DIRECTIVES} from 'ionic-angular';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
    selector        : 'med-search',
    templateUrl     : 'build/component/search/search.component.html',
    directives      :   [IONIC_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class SearchBar {
    private focused : boolean;
    private keyword : any;
    /**
     * constructor
     */
    constructor(private navCtrl : NavController){
    }

    animateComponent(){
      this.focused = true;
    }
};
```

And search bar template:

```
<ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)" [(ngModel)]="keyword" [ngClass]="{'focused' : focused}" (ionFocus)="animateComponent()"></ion-searchbar>
```

I am trying to achieve this simple task: when the user focuses on the search bar, animate the search-bar's container (for example, increase it's width etc.)

Well, if it was jQuery, I would achieve this task pretty easily.
In angualr2 it seems a bit complicated.

I thought maybe using the ***:host*** selector I could achieve my goal, but found out that I am not able to know if the search-bar is focused or not.
I also thought about EventEmitter, but it sounds like an overkill and it did not work as expected.
Is there anyway to apply a class to a parent, depanding on it's child components?

Does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Couldn't you do this entirely with CSS3 transitions?

Comment: @pixelbits well ufcourse I tried. But I do not know any working technique to refer the parent of a certain element. Therefore I'm not able to change the parent when the child input is focused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I finally resolved the issue using the `@Output` decorator.

I added a `changedFocus` property to the `searchBar` component:

```
@Output() changedFocus : EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
```

And as well added the event handlers in the searchbar:

```
  /**
   * executed when the form is focused
   */
  focus(){
    this.changedFocus.emit(true);
  }

  /**
   * executed when the form is blured
   */
  blur(){
    this.changedFocus.emit(false);
  }
```

Then, in the `Header` component I added a `focused` property:

```
private focused : boolean;
```

And a `changeFocus` method:

```
  /**
   * change element focus
   */
  changeFocus(){
    this.focused = !this.focused;
  }
```

Which is executed everytime the focus state changes on the child component.
That gave me the wanted result.